# Improve function that converts serialized object in dot notation into js object

Tags: javascript

I have the string `"presentation.launchBehavior.newWindow"`, which needs to be de-serialized into object:

```
var obj = {presentation: {launchBehavior: 'newWindow'}}
```

The last string after dot should be value, while other strings should be converted to strings. I've written the function to do that:

```
function des(obj, property, index, ar) {
    var isLastCall = ar.length - 1 === index;
    if (isLastCall) {
        return;
    }

    var isNextLastCall = ar.length - 2 === index;
    if (isNextLastCall) {
        obj[property] = ar[ar.length - 1];
        return obj;
    } else {
        obj[property] = {};
        return obj[property];
    }
}

var obj = {};
"presentation.launchBehavior.newWindow".split(".").reduce(des, obj);
obj.presentation.launchBehavior // newWindow
```

It's working, but I'd like to improve it to return the resulting object instead of having to create a variable outside the function. How can I do that? Maybe internals of the function can be improved as well.

Comment: If you want to improve working code you should post it on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduceRight`:

```js
const des = str => str.split(".").reduceRight( (prev, key) => ({[key]: prev}) );

console.log(des("presentation.launchBehavior.newWindow"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

```js
function des(str) {
  var props = (typeof str === "string") ? str.split('.') : str;
  return props.length > 1 ? {[props[0]]: des(props.slice(1))}
                           : props[0];
}

console.log(des("presentation.launchBehavior.newWindow"));
```

It uses array computed properties (`var o = {[key]: val}`). It may not work on old browsers. For old browsers, you will have to first create the object assign then property (`var o = {}; o[key] = val;`).

Comment: thanks a lot, the answer with `reduceRight` looks cleaner - what do you think?

Comment: Yes, it is better, and clever.