# How to write a function that inlines object properties

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var ob = {
    view: {
        name: 'zpo',
        params: {
            taskId: 3,
            zuka: 'v'
        }
    }
}
```

I need to have this object in the following form:

```
{
    "view.name":"zpo",
    "view.params.taskId":3,
    "view.params.zuka":"v"
}
```

I have written a function that can do that, but the problem is that it requires external variables passed to it. Here is this function:

```
function inline(o, result, container) {
    for (var p in o) {
        if (typeof o[p] === "object") {
            inline(o[p], result.length > 0 ? result+'.'+p : p, container);
        } else {
            container[result + '.' + p] = o[p];
        }
    }
}

var ob = {
    view: {
        name: 'zpo',
        params: {
            taskId: 3,
            zuka: 'v'
        }
    }
}

var c = {};
var r = inline(ob, '', c);
```

Is there any way to write this function to return correct result without the need to pass `result` and `container` external variables?

Comment: Before you try to do something unnecessary: why do you need it in that format? Why not *just* use the `view` object inside that `ob`? As for your code problem: no it doesn't, just make the function returning, put that `container` as first function line `container = {}` and then end the function on `return container`. Basic return pattern.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. can you please provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that does not require any parameters.

```js
// Return an array containing the [key, value] couples of an object.
const objEntries = o => Object.keys(o).map(k => [k, o[k]]);

// Create an object from an array of [key, value] couples.
const entriesObj = (entries, init={}) => entries.reduce((result, [key, val]) => {
  result[key] = val;
  return result;
}, init);

// Reduce on the object entries (as returned by objEntries) with an empty object as
// initialiser.
const inline = (o) => objEntries(o).reduce((result, [key, val]) => {
  if(val instanceof Object){
    // If the value is an object, recursively inline it.
    const inlineVal = inline(val);
    // Prefix each property names of inlineVal with the key of val and add the
    // properties to the result object.
    entriesObj(
      objEntries(inlineVal).map(([subK, subVal]) => [key + '.' + subK, subVal]),
      result
    );
  } else {
    // If val is not an object, just add it to the result as is.
    result[key] = val;
  }
  // Return the result.
  return result;
}, {});

var ob = {
    view: {
        name: 'zpo',
        params: {
            taskId: 3,
            zuka: 'v'
        }
    }
}

var r = inline(ob);
console.log(r);
```

I used arrow functions and destructuring. Old browsers won't support it. If you need to support them, just replace the arrow functions with regular functions and manually destructure the arguments.

Comment: thanks, can you please take a look at [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785593/improve-function-that-converts-serialized-object-in-dot-notation-into-js-object) with the related problem?

Comment: Sorry its 0:45 in my part of the world. I'm going to sleep now. I'll have a look tomorrow if you do not have an answer until then.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how the function you wrote works) Can you please provide elaborate on the main ideas you used?

Comment: Are you familiar with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? This is the key here.

Comment: yeah, sure, but it's mixed into a recursion here, so it's a bit difficult to understand what its function is)

Comment: I added some more comments.

Comment: yeah, you just commented what's obvious from the code itself. Well, let me try to outline the general pattern and I'll ask some more specific questions along the way

Comment: I am not sure what I can give you more.

Comment: yeah, sure, thanks anyways, great working function, I'll try to wrap my head around it. As a side note, do you work with algorithms? Just trying to understand how you came up with the solution)

Comment: Well, I have been coding since more than 10 years now. And actually, I already attempted to do this exact same kind of development in the past. This solution is way better than the one I wrote back then.

Comment: I see, I've been coding for some time too, but I haven't had much exposure to algorithms so I find it hard to come up with the solutions like these on the fly)

Comment: I made one last edit in an attempt to make it a bit more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, you want to avoid to call your `inline()` function with *"empty"* params.

You could catch this case in your function directly:

```
function inline(o, result, container) {
    result = result || '';
    container = container || {};
    ...
}

var r = inline(ob);
```

you would still need this params for the recursive part of your function.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is awesome!

```
function inline(o, result, container) {
  result = result || '';
  container = container || {};
  for (var p in o) {
    if (typeof o[p] === "object") {
      inline(o[p], result.length > 0 ? result+'.'+p : p, container);
    } else {
      container[result + '.' + p] = o[p];
    }
  }
}

var r = inline(ob);
```

Comment: 13 seconds late, my friend :D